# Swift 1.2 NSAttributedString from HTML-String

Tags: ios

I am trying to convert a HTML String to a NSAttributedString in Swift 1.2. Here is the code I wrote to do this job:

```
let data = html.dataUsingEncoding(NSUnicodeStringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true)!
    var error: NSError?
    let attrStr = NSAttributedString(
        data: data,
        options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType],
        documentAttributes: nil,
        error: &error)
    if error != nil {
        print(error)
        print(error!.userInfo)
    }
```

I tried this code in Objective C and it works fine but in Swift 1.2 I always get this error:

**Optional(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=259 "The operation couldn’t be completed.**
**(Cocoa error 259.)")Optional([:])**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can't replicate it in my Playground. Are you sure your `html` string is valid HTML?

Comment: Yes I had test it before in a browser and the UIWebView shows everything correctly.